# use commandline arguments in a sed command

Tags: bash, command-line, sed

I want to use commandline arguments in a sed command, where I am currently wrapping the arguments in ''. My command is:

```
mycomputer$ sed 's/^\(.\{'$1'\}\)./\1'$2'/' out2.fa 2 A
```

which essentially looks at a line in a file, and changes the 2nd position to an A. This works when I hardcode it in, but the above results in:

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 21: Invalid content of \{\}
```

also should I be using $2 and $3 as the commandline arguments given that the filename is technically the first argument?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure that `$1`, `$2`… and so on can be accessed from command line.

Instead, you could try to run your line from a function. You definitely can pass argument to functions.

```
foo() { sed 's/^\(.\{'"$2"'\}\)./\1'"$3"'/' "$1"; }
foo out2.fa 2 A
```

**Edit**: As suggested in comments, I added double-quotes around the argument references to prevent spaces from breaking command parsing (That should not be necessary around `$2` as we just pass an integer, but it's much better for `$1` and `$3`.

Comment: @mklement0 That's right. I've just edited my post to add double-quotes. Thanks for providing details about the functioning of arguments, that was instructive for me as well :)

Answer (score 5):

**Update**:

While the information in the next section (the original answer) is true in general, the **real problem is the OP's *mistaken belief* that (positional) *arguments* (`$1`, ...) can be passed to `sed` with arguments *after* the 1st post-script (the filename) argument**.

**However, *all* arguments after `sed`'s script argument are, in fact, *filename* arguments**, and **`sed` has *no* concept of *other* types of arguments or shell variables in general**:

- Any **references to shell variables or arguments must be *embedded in the script***, using **up-front string expansion (interpolation)**.
- Generally, arguments `$1`, ... are *shell-only constructs* that refer to the arguments passed to either the *current shell* or, inside a shell *function*, that function.

---

##### Original answer:

- [@Qeole's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24195644/45375) provides a solution based on a *shell function*, which is the **best option**.
- Alternatively, use *variables*:

  ```bash
  countBefore=2 newChar='A'
  sed 's/^\(.\{'"$countBefore"'\}\)./\1'"$newChar"'/' out2.fa
  ```

Note:

- You say `changes the 2nd position to an A`. Actually, your command effectively replaces the *3rd* character (`$countBefore+1`-nth).)
- You say,  `I am currently wrapping the arguments in ''`. Actually, it's the *`sed` script that's enclosed in `''`*, and you're *splicing in* **unquoted** argument references. My variable-based solution *double-quotes* the spliced-in variable references for robustness.
- The alternative to splicing in variable references is to simply *double-quote the entire `sed` script* and use *embedded variable references*:

  ```bash
  sed "s/^\(.\{$countBefore\}\)./\1$newChar/" out2.fa
  ```

---

`sed: -e expression #1, char 21: Invalid content of \{\}` is GNU `sed`'s way of saying that what you specified to go inside `{...}` (`$1`) does not amount to a valid repetition-count expression.

In other words: the value of `$1` in your case is NONE of the following:

- a mere *decimal number* (e.g., `2`)
- a decimal number followed by `,`, optionally followed by another decimal number (e.g., `2,` or `2,3`)
- `,`, followed by a decimal number (e.g., `,3`)

Make sure that `$1` is one of the above.