# calling and changing a file using sed command within a function

Tags: bash, shell, sed

Hi I have wrapped a sed command (which works out it's own) within a shell function.

```
#!/bin/bash

snp2fasta() { 
sed -i "s/^\(.\{'$2'\}\)./\1'$3'/" $1; 
}
```

and call it with

```
$ ./snp2fasta input.txt 45 A
```

no changes are made to input.txt

However if I simply do

```
$ sed -i 's/^\(.\{45\}\)./\1A/' input.txt
```

then this works and the file is changed by changing the 45th character to an A.

However when wrapping into a shell script (to handle command line variables) the shell script snp2fasta.sh runs fine, but no changes are made to the file.

why is this?

Comment: It will be an escaping problem. put `set -x` just before the sed call to see what it actually runs.

Comment: i get no output from terminal when using set -x before the sed command

Comment: sorry @Jayesh - made a mistake - I do actually put the file as argument one and have edited post

Comment: hi @Jayesh I call ./snp2fasta in the second code block - I call it from the command line. is that what you mean?

Comment: @brucezepplin ok..look it. The shell doesn't expand variables inside single quotes. Try with expand variable in `""`.like   `sed -i 's/^\(.\{"$2"\}\)./\1"$3"/' "$1";`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you put it into a script, no more need of the function call ouside the script, use it directly intor the script.

Like on the other related post ( [Use argument to...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24194460/use-commandline-arguments-in-a-sed-command)) about state it (to secure thje $1,2 and 3 content)

```
#!/bin/bash

# argument passed to script (or any other source if needed like intern to script)
File=$1
Place=$2
NewChar=$3

# sed with unambigous variable content
sed -i "s/^\(.\{${Place}\}\)./\1${NewChar}/" ${File}
```